# use aws sqs for different message types

Tags: amazon-web-services, java-8, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I am using AWS SQS and Spring JMS in my project. I have my method with @JmsListener(destination = "queue_name"). I want to use this queue for two different types of messages.

Since this listener is configured to this queue it receives both types of messages. What I am trying to achieve is to ignore message of one type. (Sender is adding a MessageAttribute while sending message to Queue). So, is there a way to just ignore message coming from sender 2 so this method won't process them.

Also, I have DLQ set on this queue with max receives as 5. So if message is not processed in first 5 attempts it gets moved to DLQ.

Please do share your suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct solution is to use 2 different queues; SQS can't filter the messages delivered by any property, so as you are seeing, when the client reads the message and doesn't process it, it is going to end up in your DLQ quicker.

Queues are free, so having multiple won't cost any more.

Comment: Thank you E.J Brennan for inputs, what you mentioned in your response makes more sense to me. I have another use case where i need your inputs. I want to notify message sender once consumed message is processed by consumer, would you recommend to use new SQS for this use case as well ? Please share if there is another way/approach that would suit best for this use case. Thanks much.

Comment: You could notify the 'sender' either via a message posted to yet another queue (the sender must monitor that queue to consume the messages),

Comment: Thank you E.J Brennan, much appreciate your inputs.

Comment: If the messages are time dependent or related data eg open and close than this is pretty bad as you get more out of order.  eg business order is Open Close but get it as Close Open.